# How to return a value from a Thread to another class

Tags: java, multithreading, hash

I am currently writing a java application to do a brute force attack on an MD5 hash. I made a JFrame that takes the uses hash input.

[image: Picture 1]

for example i hashed the word "password" to MD5. (seen in picture 1) when the JButton is clicked
it will send the hash to a Comparative class that will iterate trough all the possibilities in sequential order. IE go from AAAAAAAA. then to AAAAAAAB and so on. and hashes them. If the hash of the possibility matched the hash of the word "password". A dialog box will appear informing the user that a match has been found.

My problem is that i don't know how to return a value from a thread in a class that `implements Runnable` to the GUI class without using setters and getters.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource().equals(bruteForceButton))
    {
        enterLabel.setText("Brute force in process");

        String enteredHash = input.getText();
        int lengthOfPass = (int) length.getSelectedItem();

        //Send the information to the comparative class
        HashComparative comp = new HashComparative();
        comp.setHash(enteredHash);
        comp.setLengthOfPass(lengthOfPass);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(comp);

        t1.start();
        hash.setText(comp.getHash());
    }
```

this starts the thread sending the appropriate data to the comparative class.
And here is the other class.

```
public class HashComparative implements Runnable
{

    private String h;
    private int l;
    private Thread thread;


    public void start()
    {
        thread = new Thread(this, "");
        thread.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {   
        try
        {
            //CODE WILL GO HERE TO COMPUTE HASHES 

            setHash(h);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

    public void setHash(String h)
    {
        this.h = h;
    }
    //Returns the hash currently being compared
    public String getHash()
    {
        return h;
    }
}
```

While the brute force is in operation. I want the display the hashes that it tries by sending the hash string back to the GUI class and set the text to a JLabel. For Example

[image: Picture 2]

I have looked online but can't find an answer to this. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Use an `ExecutorService`, and implement `Callable` instead of `Runnable`.

Comment: could you go into a little more in depth please?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to implement is rather [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead of `Runnable` as this interface allows you to return a value which is what you want here. As you can only provide `Runnable` to a `Thread`, you need to use a pool thread instead, that you can create from [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html). It will allow you to `submit` your task as a `Callable` or a `Runnable`, and then get a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to be able to wait until the task is completed successfully or not.

In your case you can create a pool of only one thread using [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--)

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
...
```

Then your class `HashComparative` will be:

```
public class HashComparative implements Callable<String> {
    private final String enteredHash;
    private final int lengthOfPass;

    public HashComparative(final String enteredHash, final int lengthOfPass) {
        this.enteredHash = enteredHash;
        this.lengthOfPass = lengthOfPass;
    } 
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        //CODE WILL GO HERE TO COMPUTE HASHES
        return h;
    }
    ...
}
```

And finally you will submit your task as next:

```
HashComparative comp = new HashComparative(enteredHash, lengthOfPass);
Future<String> future = executor.submit(comp);
hash.setText(future.get());
```

---

> What can be used to display the unmatching hashes?

The design pattern that matches the best with this kind of need is [`Observer`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Indeed here you want to make your UI observes the progress of your computation. Out of the box, you have [`Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) and [`Observer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) that you can use to implement this pattern.

So here for the sake of simplicity, you could make your class `HashComparative` extends `Observable` to be able to notify the `Observers` (your UI here) any time a new hash is being processed.

```
public class HashComparative extends Observable implements Callable<String> {

    private String h;

    ...

    public void setHash(String h) {
        this.h = h;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public String getHash() {
        return h;
    }
}
```

Then in your UI, you can change the text accordingly by implementing `Observer`

```
final HashComparative comp = new HashComparative(enteredHash, lengthOfPass);
comp.addObserver(new Observer() {
    @Override
    public void update(final Observable o, final Object arg) {
        HashComparative hc = (HashComparative)o;
        hash.setText(hc.getHash());
    }
});
```

---

If it goes too fast, you could also use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to only change the hash displayed after a given amount of time. You could for example create it using `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` to have only one thread then refresh the hash as next:

```
final HashComparative comp = new HashComparative(enteredHash, lengthOfPass);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        hash.setText(comp.getHash());
    }
}, 1L, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This will refresh the hash displayed every second. With this approach you have no need to extend `Observable` anymore, you will only need to make `h` `volatile` as it will be modified and accessed by several threads concurrently

```
public class HashComparative implements Callable<String> {

    private volatile String h;
    ...
}
```

Comment: will it display all the hashes it tries to compare or as you said the last one before the task is complete? I tried using a simple for loop printing from 1 to 100 just to test how it worked. and it only displays "100" on the JLabel after a few seconds.. And its not a case of the for loop being to fast for it to display, as i used a `Thread.sleep(100)` between each iteration

Comment: yes it only gives the result. It is actually an answer to "My problem is that i don't know how to return a value from a thread"

Comment: for me it should only return the possible match or throw an exception if no match could be found. Or if you use Java 8 it should return an Optional<String> instead of String, the value will then be present if there is a match otherwise there is no match

Comment: Do you know how what can be used to display the unmatching hashes? Appreciate the help Nicolas

Comment: you mean that you want to display all the hashes tested in HashComparative?

Comment: Yes. From "AAAAAAAA", "AAAAAAAB" and so on, to be hashed, and sent back to the actionPerformed method. then displayed in in the JLabel while the brute force is being done. Can it be done?

Comment: @Nicolas Filotto I have a similar use case, trying to convert AsyncTasks to ExecutorService to return a List from a Room database. Another answer suggests using submit() on ExecutorService and get() on the Dao method (see stackoverflow.com/questions/52242933/room-database-query). Would appreciate your thoughts on that approach versus the approach using a Callable and a Future.